# Showing alert dialog on dropdown select in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show an alert dialog on dropdown select in jQuery but it doesn't seem to be working. What am I doing wrong? My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/AyCFt/6/

**HTML**

```
<select>
  <option selected="selected">Please select your Login</option>
  <option>--------------------------</option>
  <option id="#projectmanager">Project Manager</option>
  <option id="#projectmanager2">Project Manager 2</option>
</select>​
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#projectmanager").click(function(){
        alert("Hello");
    });
    $("#projectmanager 2").click(function(){
        alert("Hello to you too!");
    });
});
```

​

Comment: If you are only interested in displaying the alerts please see jsfiddle.net/AyCFt/13 Otherwise, please see my full answer below (edited to both cover the simple case in the question's sample code and the more complex cases you might want to handle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can show a unique alert box for each projectmanager.

```
<select id='ddselect'>
      <option selected="selected" >Please select your Login</option>
      <option>--------------------------</option>
      <option id="projectmanager">Project Manager</option>
      <option id="projectmanager2">Project Manager 2</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ddselect").change(function(){
        if($("#ddselect option:selected").attr("id") == "projectmanager"){
            alert("Project manager 1 alert");
        }
        if($("#ddselect option:selected").attr("id") == "projectmanager2"){
            alert("Project manager 2 alert");
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

An elegant and also flexible  way of doing this:  http://jsfiddle.net/AyCFt/13/ 
The jsFiddle just tackles the question asked (displaying the alerts).  The code below shows that the code is much more flexible, but avoids the if/switch statements of other answers if they are not needed.

**HTML**: I added an id in the select element and custom attributesnamed data-alert containing the message for each option that needs to display an alert upon being selected.  These attributes are valid in HTML5 and forward, but they work fine in earlier HTML versions also:

```
<select id="selectAlert">
  <option selected="selected">Please select your Login</option>
  <option>--------------------------</option>
  <option id="#projectmanager" data-alert="Hello">Project Manager</option>
  <option id="#projectmanager2" data-alert="Hello to you too">Project Manager 2</option>ello
</select>
```

**Javascript (version 1)**:  If you just want the alerts and are a fan of brevity and clean code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#selectAlert").change(function(){
        var alertMsg = $(this).find(":selected").attr("data-alert");
        if(alertMsg) alert(alertMsg);
    });
});
```

Note that this solution does not force you display the text or the value of options.  You are free to choose any alert message exactly as you wanted.

**WHY DO THINGS THIS WAY?**  This kind of solution decouples logic from data.  So if you are producing the `select` using server-side code (either as part of a dynamically generated page or through AJAX) you ideally do not want to have to produce your Javascript in the same way if you can avoid it.  Whereas your code and the code in some other solutions puts the alert messages in the Javascript code, this solution puts them inside each `option`, in the HTML.

**Javascript (version 2)**: If there are more things you need to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectAlert").change(function(){
        var $selected = $(this).find(":selected"); //faster than $("#selectAlert :selected") as it only searches among the options in the select and not the whole DOM like another answer's solution
        //some code: you can do what you want with $selected here get it's value, its id, etc etc
        var alertMsg = $selected.attr("data-alert")
        if(alertMsg) alert(alertMsg);
        //some more code here
    });
});
```

**PROBLEM WITH CODE POSTED IN THE QUESTION:**
The problem with the code you posted was that you were using `click` on the options of the select element.  As you discovered this event is not defined for the individual options.

**A GENERAL POINT ABOUT UI EVENTS:** In general, it is best to try to work with device-independent, more "semantic" events wherever possibly.  In this case the event we are using is one that tells us that the value of the select has changed.  It does not matter if the user did so using the mouse, the keyboard, or touch!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code. It will work for you.

```
<select id='ddselect'>
          <option selected="selected" >Please select your Login</option>
          <option>--------------------------</option>
          <option id="#projectmanager">Project Manager</option>
          <option id="#projectmanager2">Project Manager 2</option>
    </select>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#ddselect").change(function(){
            alert("Hello");
        });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but if I go with this method I cannot assign unique alerts to *Project Manager* and *Project Manager 2*.

Comment: try this alert($(this).val());

Answer (score 0):

Make the below change to html:

```
<select id="SelectOptions">
  <option selected="selected">Please select your Login</option>
  <option>--------------------------</option>
  <option id="#projectmanager">Project Manager</option>
  <option id="#projectmanager2">Project Manager 2</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​
```

Make the below change to the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SelectOptions").change(function(){
         alert($("#SelectOptions option:selected")[0].text);
    });
});
```

This will display the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above you can use `onchange` on the `select` element. to respond uniquely to each value you can use a `switch` statement like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/AyCFt/11/

Answer (score 0):

This is but one way to do it (and depending on your final implementation, there's probably a better way to go about this).

Add `value` attributes to your markup so that the message is contained in the value:

```
<select id="changeMe">
    <option selected="selected">Please select your Login</option>
    <option disabled="disabled">--------------------------</option>
    <option id="projectmanager" value="Hello">Project Manager</option>
    <option id="projectmanager2" value="Hello to you too">Project Manager 2</option>
</select>​
```

Since `option` elements don't [often] receive `.click()` events, it's much better to add a `.change()` handler to the `select` element and go from there:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select#changeMe').change(function(e) {
        var self = $(this), //cache lookup
            selected = self.children('option:selected'), //get the selected option
            i = selected.index('select#changeMe option'), //grab the index, relative to all options
            message = selected.val(); //get the message
        if (i > 1) { //ignore "Please select" and "---"
            alert(message);
        }
    });
});​
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AyCFt/12/

Answer (score 0):

To customise the alert message, you would either need to run a 'switch' statement (or a switch-like series of 'if' statements) in the Javascript code, or encode the alert message into the HTML and access that (example here http://jsfiddle.net/AFguq/):

```
<select id="SelectOptions">
  <option selected="selected">Please select your Login</option>
  <option>--------------------------</option>
  <option id="#projectmanager" alertText="Hello">Project Manager</option>
  <option id="#projectmanager2" alertText="Hello to you too">Project Manager 2</option>
</select>​
```

(javascript:)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SelectOptions").change(function(){
         alert($("#SelectOptions option:selected").attr('alertText'));
    });
});​
```